# "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

Tags: python, numpy

```
def VerletNextV(v_t,a_t,a_t_plus_h):

  v_t_plus_h = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  #<-- find v_t_plus_h[0], v_t_plus_h[1], v_t_plus_h[2], here -->
  for i in range(0,len(v_t_plus_h)):
    v_t_plus_h[i] = v_t + .5*(a_t[i] + a_t_plus_h[i])
  return v_t_plus_h
```

Next I have this line:

```
nV[i] = VerletNextV(V[i],A[i], a_t_h)
```

which is giving me the error that I specified in my title:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

This is driving me insane - what is the problem here? `nV[i]` is a declared using:

```
nV = numpy.zeros((N,3))
```

Comment: What are the input variables `V[i],A[i], a_t_h`?

Comment: You'll want to check what `VerletNextV` is actually returning.  If it is returning a list of 3 numbers then this should work, but it seems likely that is is probably not.

Comment: Unrelatedly, it's not necessary in Python to create a list of zeros if you're just going to replace all the values in the list.  You can just as easily declare `v_t_plus_h = []` and use `v_t_plus_h.append` in the loop.  Or use a list comprehension.  Though since it seems like you're doing vector arithmetic it might make more sense if you velocity and acceleration vectors were also Numpy arrays; then you would just array arithmetic and no explicit loops in Python.

Comment: Initializing a `numpy` array, and then filling it row by row is a valid approach.  Building an array from a comprehension is also good.  That is, if you can't do it with vector operations.

Comment: Try this: `nV[i,:] = VerletNextV(V[i],A[i], a_t_h)`.  You could also print the shape of both sides of that equation before hand. The error looks like `nV[i]` is a scalar, and `VerletNextV()` is a list.